# Why Does React Render Children Before Parents?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I've run into this problem a few times now. Child components rely on their parents for certain props, yet for some reason React is rendering many of these children before their parents, creating a no-op. It doesn't make any sense to me why React would do this, can someone explain why this happens?

Example:

In App.jsx I have:

```
<div className='container'>
    {this.state.loggedIn ? this.changeView() : <Landing />}
</div>
```

in render(), so once user logs in, changeView is fired which returns `<GroceryList user={this.state.user} />`. This calls:

```
const GroceryList = (props) => (
  <div>
    <AddIngredients ingredients={props.user.groceryList} />
  </div>
);
```

which then calls its child AddIngredients, which relies on props.ingredients to render in the following code:

```
const IngredientList = [];

  for(let i=0; i<this.props.ingredients.length; i++) {
    IngredientList.push(<Ingredient
      key={i}
      index={i}
      value={this.props.ingredients[i]}
      handleDeleteIngredient={this.handleDeleteIngredient}
      handleUpdateIngredient={this.handleUpdateIngredient}
    />);
  }
```

When I first login in the app I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` but if I refresh the page it works.

Comment: I've worked with React for two years now and haven't come across this problem. Could you include a code example in your question to explain what you mean?

Comment: @PatrickHund Updated question

Comment: It renders children from the inside out so that when `componentDidMount` is called, you're guaranteed for all of your children to have mounted. You could then do `this.refs.child.refs.etc`. Without mounting children first, it would be chaos, and lifecyle hooks wouldn't be meaningful

Comment: It looks like you're just rendering a component before the data is available, not asking why children mount first.

Comment: @AndyRay So you're saying when `componentDidMount` inside App is called, it's already rendered all children? Is there a way around this? It seems strange to me that you'd ever want to render children before parents.

Comment: Data should flow from the parents to the children when using props because these are inputs. If the property value is not available at the time the parent is rendering, they won't be available when the child renders. I think what you want is a check that `this.props.ingredients` is defined (not `undefined` or `null`) in `IngredientList` before attempting to use the property. The data is likely missing the first time you load the page and is causing a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not what you have mentioned in the question. The problem is that you are accessing the length of 'groceryList' when it is not loaded yet. You can solve this problem with safe navigation methods or you can solve this like below:

```
const GroceryList = (props) => (
  <div>
    {props.user.groceryList && <AddIngredients ingredients={props.user.groceryList} />}
  </div>
);
```

However, there are several syntaxes that you can use depend on your code and your preference.